# Numpy einsum outer sum of 2d-arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I tried searching for an answer, but couldn't find what I needed. Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Suppose I have a 2d-array with shape `(n, n*m)`. What I want to do is an outer sum of this array to its transpose that results in an array with shape `(n*m, n*m)`. For example, suppose i have

```
A = array([[1., 1., 2., 2.],
           [1., 1., 2., 2.]])
```

I want to do an outer sum of `A` and `A.T` such that the output is:

```
>>> array([[2., 2., 3., 3.],
           [2., 2., 3., 3.],
           [3., 3., 4., 4.],
           [3., 3., 4., 4.]])
```

Note that `np.add.outer` does not work because it ravels in the inputs into vectors. I can achieve something similar by doing

```
np.tile(A, (2, 1)) + np.tile(A.T, (1, 2))
```

but this does not seem reasonable when `n` and `m` are reasonably large (`n > 100` and `m > 1000`). Is it possible to write this sum using `einsum`? I just can't seem to figure out `einsum`.

Comment: `einsum` implements sum of products; it can be used for outer products, but not outer sums.  With the `tile` you make two temporary arrays that are the size of the target, right?  Is the problem so large that you can only afford to have one array of that size?

Comment: Can't you make this more diagnostic by changing the 2nd row of `A`?

Comment: Stepping back from the example, and focusing on the dimensions.  `A` can be reshaped to (n,n,m), and the target to (n,m,n,m). If we can create a sum that is (n,n,m,m) we can transpose to get the right shape.  Will the values be right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To leverage `broadcasting`, we need to break it down to `3D` and then permute axes and add -

```
n = A.shape[0]
m = A.shape[1]//n
a = A.reshape(n,m,n) # reshape to 3D
out = (a[None,:,:,:] + a.transpose(1,2,0)[:,:,None,:]).reshape(n*m,-1)
```

Sample run for verification -

```
In [359]: # Setup input array
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: n,m = 3,4
     ...: A = np.random.randint(1,10,(n,n*m))

In [360]: # Original soln
     ...: out0 = np.tile(A, (m, 1)) + np.tile(A.T, (1, m))

In [361]: # Posted soln
     ...: n = A.shape[0]
     ...: m = A.shape[1]//n
     ...: a = A.reshape(n,m,n)
     ...: out = (a[None,:,:,:] + a.transpose(1,2,0)[:,:,None,:]).reshape(n*m,-1)

In [362]: np.allclose(out0, out)
Out[362]: True
```

Timings with large `n`,`m` -

```
In [363]: # Setup input array
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: n,m = 100,100
     ...: A = np.random.randint(1,10,(n,n*m))

In [364]: %timeit np.tile(A, (m, 1)) + np.tile(A.T, (1, m))
1 loop, best of 3: 407 ms per loop

In [365]: %%timeit
     ...: # Posted soln
     ...: n = A.shape[0]
     ...: m = A.shape[1]//n
     ...: a = A.reshape(n,m,n)
     ...: out = (a[None,:,:,:] + a.transpose(1,2,0)[:,:,None,:]).reshape(n*m,-1)
1 loop, best of 3: 219 ms per loop
```

**Further performance boost with `numexpr`**

We can leverage [`multi-core` with `numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) for large data and to gain memory efficiency and hence performance -

```
import numexpr as ne

n = A.shape[0]
m = A.shape[1]//n
a = A.reshape(n,m,n)
p1 = a[None,:,:,:]
p2 = a.transpose(1,2,0)[:,:,None,:]
out = ne.evaluate('p1+p2').reshape(n*m,-1)
```

Timings with same large `n`, `m` setup -

```
In [367]: %%timeit
     ...: # Posted soln
     ...: n = A.shape[0]
     ...: m = A.shape[1]//n
     ...: a = A.reshape(n,m,n)
     ...: p1 = a[None,:,:,:]
     ...: p2 = a.transpose(1,2,0)[:,:,None,:]
     ...: out = ne.evaluate('p1+p2').reshape(n*m,-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 152 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is

```
(A.reshape(-1,*A.shape).T+A)[:,0,:]
```

I think this will take a lot of memory with `n>100` and `m>1000`.

but isn't this the same as

```
np.add.outer(A,A)[:,0,:].reshape(4,-1)
```